# exceeded maximum execution time in google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets. I want to match column C of `spreadsheet1` with column A of `spreadsheet2`. Both of these spreadsheet has records more than 8000. Due to huge number of records my script constantly gives `exceeded maximum execution time` error. Here is the script

```
function compare() {

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetList1=ss.getSheetByName("spreadsheet1");
  var sheetList2=ss.getSheetByName("spreadsheet2");

   var sheet1Data=sheetList1.getRange(2,3,sheetList1.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

   var sheet2Data=sheetList2.getRange(1,1,sheetList2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

   for (i in sheet2Data){
    var row = 2;
      for (j in sheet1Data){
        if (sheet1Data[j][0]==sheet2Data[i][0]){
           sheetList1.getRange("A"+row).setValue('Inactive');           
        }
        row++;
      }


   }

}
```

any suggestions for optimizing this script. Or how to handle this error ?
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

Thanks for the wonderful reply. There is one issue. If I push data in `newSheet1Data` array before the `if` statement then it write `Inactive` twice. i.e if there are two rows it writes `inactive` to four rows.Like

```
newSheet1Data.push(sheet1Data[j]); 
        if (sheet1Data[j][2]==sheet2Data[i][0]){
          newSheet1Data[j][0]='Inactive';
        }
```

If I push data inside `if` statement and no match occur then it does not find row and give this error `TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "Inactive"`.  Like

```
if (sheet1Data[j][0]==sheet2Data[i][0]){
           newSheet1Data.push(sheet1Data[j]);
           newSheet1Data[j][0]='Inactive';           
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid any calls to spreadsheet API in a loop, especially when you have so much data in it.

The idea is to play only with arrays and to write the result back once it is finished.
The code below does it (based on you code if data in col C sheet1 is the same as data in sheet2 col A then write a string in sheet1 col A ).
I hope I made no mistake but I didn't have the opportunity to test my code... it might need some debugging ;-)

```
function compare() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetList1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetList2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet1Data=sheetList1.getDataRange().getValues();// get the whole sheet in an array
  var sheet2Data=sheetList2.getRange(1,1,sheetList2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var newSheet1Data = [] ; // create a new array to collect data
   for (i=0;i<sheet1Data.length;++i){
      for (j=0;j<sheet2Data.length;++j){
      if(i!=j){continue};
        newSheet1Data.push(sheet1Data[i]); // add the full row to target array
        if (sheet1Data[i][2]==sheet2Data[j][0]){
          newSheet1Data[i][0]='Inactive';//if condition is true change column A
          break
        }
      }
   }
  newSheet1Data.shift();// remove first row (probably headers ?)
  sheetList1.getRange(2,1,newSheet1Data.length,newSheet1Data[0].length).setValues(newSheet1Data);  // write back to sheet1 in one batch
}
```

---

EDIT : after seing your doc I understand what you want more exactly...
here is the new code (tested on your SS)

```
function compare() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetList1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetList2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet1Data=sheetList1.getDataRange().getValues();// get the whole sheet in an array
  var sheet2Data=sheetList2.getRange(1,1,sheetList2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var newSheet1Data = [] ; // create a new array to collect data
  for (i=0;i<sheet1Data.length;++i){
    newSheet1Data.push(sheet1Data[i]); // add the full row to target array
       for (j=0;j<sheet2Data.length;++j){
         if (sheet1Data[i][2]==sheet2Data[j][0]){
          newSheet1Data[i][0]='Inactive';//if condition is true change column A
          break;// don't continue after condition was true, this will speed up the process
        }
      }
   }
  newSheet1Data.shift();// remove first row (probably headers ?)
  sheetList1.getRange(2,1,newSheet1Data.length,newSheet1Data[0].length).setValues(newSheet1Data);  // write back to sheet1 in one batch
}
```

Comment: sorry I had made a typo in code, last line od code : must of course use the sheetName to use .getRange(), I updated my answer.

Comment: I finally tested it, this version works as expected, the loops were not suitable for this logic.

Comment: Are you sure ? Data is pushed only once... if you get 2 copies of a row I really don't know why. Could you share a copy of your spreadsheet to see what happens or at least a sample of data to est on.?   My test runs fine.  Btw the error you get after changing the place of the push is normal, the row you try to write to doesn't exist at this time. It has to come first.

Comment: btw, could you please tell us how long it takes now with this script ? thanks

Comment: Also : I added a line in the code to speed it up (a bit more !) see the break; + comment

Comment: Its taking still 5 minutes time. if data become little more I guess the script will stop working again.

Comment: Script stop working again because more data was added to the sheet.

Comment: Are you using **exactly** the code I suggested or did you modify something ? Also : could you add a Logger.log(i) in the code right after the line newSheet1Data.push(sheet1Data[i]); to see how long it takes to execute the j loop ? if this code can't do it I suggest you open a new thread asking for how to do the job in multiple batches.